# Content does not size correctly to viewport

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, width, responsive

I'm a beginner on CSS and HTML, and I have to fix a problem on this website:
https://arena-supplements.com/
on the Mobile Version, when you scroll left, you still see a lot of space outside the page.

The problem seems to be the sticky header or this "go to top" button in the footer, but I have no other idea how to fix it.

Would a max-width solve this?

[image]

Comment: Hi! please try this to add in media query      -->  body, html{overflow-x:hidden;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this to add in media query**

```
body, html{overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Comment: It works!!! added to the body :) Thank you soo much